# SSIS - Need Flat File Connection Manager Expression (adding date to file name) to be recognized after package deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, ssis

SSIS - Need Flat File Connection Manager Expression (adding date to file name) to be recognized after package deployment
I have this expression that I put in the Flat File Connection Manager properties. How do I make sure that this is recognized after the package is deployed?

Here is the expression:

```
"C:\\Users\\sbolton\\source\\repos\\dcm-ado\\DWBI\\GATEWAYCONS\\DataRailsData\\GLTRAN_" +  (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + "-" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + "-" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) 
 + ".csv"
```

Comment: What do you mean by make sure it's recognised?

Comment: After I deploy my package to the server? Will it automatically know that I have this expression in the connection property? Or do I have to create a parameter or variable for it to know?

Comment: Packages don't change when you deploy them. If you have a property defined by an expression, it's defined by an expression. Expressions don't become literals on deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking, how does that get appended to your filename at runtime?

Create a variable and add your connection string into the expression.
[image]

Go to properties of the flat file connection. Expand Expression and add new Connection String. Add your variable to the Connection String value.
[image]